# Freeforms - add error

Tags: error-message, plugin-freeform, freeform

I've created a plugin that will check for a unique email address in the submissions of Freeform.
Because I don't want this check to be done with Ajax, I use the Freeform hook 'onBeforeSave'.

Whenever a email is already used, I want the user to know. I'm telling Freeforms that the form is not valid:

```
craft()->on(
    "freeform_submissions.onBeforeSave",
    function (Event $event) {

        // Let Freeform know the form is not valid
        $event->performAction = false;
    }
);
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to communicate this to the frontend. It would be nice if I could set a Freeform error message.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Freeforms (Solspace). Unfortunately there is no solution for this problem (yet). Solspace told me:

> This functionality currently isn't possible with Freeform. It's something on our feature requests list though.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Freeform before, but it looks like that [event](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/events-and-hooks/#event-onbeforesave-form) has a `model` param passed into it.

You should be able to add errors to it like any other models in Craft.

```
craft()->on(
    "freeform_submissions.onBeforeSave",
    function (Event $event) {

        // Let Freeform know the form is not valid
        $event->performAction = false;

        $event->params['model']->addError('email', 'This email is already in use!');
    }
);
```

This assumes that there is an 'email' attribute on the `Freeform_SubmissionModel` class and there is logic to display errors in your template similar to: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work.